# Resize columns to fits DataGrid in WPF dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have code where I add custom DataGrid object in a Grid column dynamically like:

```
DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
var vm = new MyViewModel();
dg.DataContext = vm;
dg.ItemsSource = vm.Items;

dg.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
dg.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;

dg.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dg.CanUserAddRows = false;
dg.CanUserResizeColumns = true;

dg.Columns.Clear();

dg.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn
{
                Header = "Name",
                Binding = new Binding(nameof(DataItem.Path)) { Converter = new PathToNameConverter() },
                //Width = DataGridLength.Auto
});
...

// here add column definition to Grid
var gridColDefs = new ColumnDefinition();
gridColDefs.Width = GridLength.Auto;
gridColDefs.MinWidth = 500;

gridElement.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridColDefs);
Grid.SetColumn(dg, gridElement.ColumnDefinitions.Count - 1);
gridElement.Children.Add(dg);

// populate datagrid items (I use Items => ObservableCollection<>)
await vm.FetchItemsAsync();

var star = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
dg.ColumnWidth = star;
foreach (var col in dg.Columns)
{
    col.Width = star;
}

dg.SelectionMode = DataGridSelectionMode.Extended;
```

After populating items in `DataGrid`, the columns are not filled to entire DataGrid width, a space remains as in picture:

[image]

What I want is to fill all columns to its DataGrid space ... I don't know where's my mistake

**UPDATE**

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();

public override Task FetchItemsAsync(string path = null)
{
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
            {
                return Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    var mainDrive = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System));
                    App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Items.Clear());

                    var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(mainDrive);
                    var files = Directory.GetFiles(mainDrive);

                    foreach (var item in folders.Union(files))
                    {
                        var isDir = FolderUtility.IsFolder(item);
                        FileSystemInfo fs = null;
                        if (isDir)
                        {
                            fs = new DirectoryInfo(item);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fs = new FileInfo(item);
                        }

                        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                Items.Add(new DataItem
                                {
                                    Path = item,
                                    Size = isDir ? FolderUtility.GetFolderSize(item) : new FileInfo(item).Length,
                                    LastModifiedDate = fs.LastWriteTimeUtc,
                                    CreationDate = fs.CreationTimeUtc
                                });
                            }
                            catch { }
                            finally { }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }

            return null;
}
```

** UPDATE 2 **
If I use

```
Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star)
```

for every column, after `await` statement, I got:

[image]

The XAML:

```
<Window ...>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DockPanel x:Name="AppContentPanel" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yes, I want to fill whole DataGrid space

Comment: Set the `Width` property to "*" then. See my answer.

Comment: `Width` of whom ?

Comment: Each `DataGridColumn`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the columns to divide the `DataGrid` equally, you could set the `Width` property of them to "*":

```
Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
```

**Edit:**

You also need to remove the `gridColDefs.Width = GridLength.Auto;` and set the  `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` property of the `ScrollViewer` to `Disabled` for the `DataGrid` to stretch as expected.

Comment: I tried in `dg.Columns.Add( ... , Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star))` but it is worst because columns have very small width before populating data

Comment: I already did, see my post, I did after await FetchAsync

Comment: See updated post

Comment: Why would the columns have "very small width before populating data"? The should fill the `DataGrid`'s space. If they don't, you have put the `DataGrid` in the wrong kind of `Panel` or messed with its `Width` somehow.

Comment: Seems will work if: `dg.Width=gridColDef.ActualWidth` after await statement

Comment: I don't know , maybe I add wrong the `DataGrid` in `Grid` ? I didn't find tutorial for that

Comment: I updated post to show how it is displayed if use `Star` width

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239088/discussion-between-snake-eyes-and-mm8).